# Populating nested dictionary from database query c#

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I have data in a database that look like this (simplified)

```
colA, colB, colC
'a',   1,   'abc'
'a',   2,   'def'
'b',   1,   'ghi'
'b',   2,   'jkl'
```

My aim is to build a nested dictionary from that table, that looks like this:

```
dict = {a: {1: 'abc'}, {2: 'def'},
        b: {1: 'ghi'}, {2: 'jkl'}}
```

I have few more nested levels in my real case. Being a database query, I imagine I can do a 'for' loop line by line

Any suggestion to an elegant/efficient way to populate a dictionary this way?

Comment: How are you reading the table from the database - datareader, datatableadapter or other?

Comment: I am executing the select query to load the data to Dataset. And from the dataset, loading to the class object.

Comment: Well my answer will work for extracting from the dataset (just use `dataset.tables["<tablename>"].AsEnumerable()` instead of `table.AsEnumerable()`. Alternatively if you can provide your class object definition I can update my answer

Answer (score 1):

This answer assumes you are using a DataTable to store your SQL results, but could be adapted to use an ORM object.

I've manually populated my DataTable like so:

```
var table= new DataTable("test");
table.Columns.AddRange(new [] { 
  new DataColumn("colA",typeof(string)), 
  new DataColumn("colB",typeof(int)),
  new DataColumn("colC",typeof(string))}
);
table.Rows.Add("a",1,"abc");
table.Rows.Add("a",2,"def");
table.Rows.Add("b",1,"ghi");
table.Rows.Add("b",2,"jkl");
```

You can populate your table using the appropriate DataTableAdapter for your database type.

Once you have the DataTable you can create your dictionary like so:

```
var result = table.AsEnumerable()
                  .GroupBy(r => r["colA"])
                  .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, 
                                g => g.GroupBy(r => r["colB"])
                                      .ToDictionary (g2 => g2.Key, 
                                                     g2 => g2.Select(r => r["ColC"])
                                                             .First()
                                                     )
                                );
```